# How to tell when a calendar event has a reminder

Tags: c#, windows-7, google-calendar-api, reminders

I am writing a windows app using c# and getting google-calendar using API v3
I manually created 2 events in google calendar using Chrome. I had 1 event with the default pop-up reminder for 10 minutes and the other event without a reminder, I clicked on the X to delete the default reminder then clicked Save.

When I used my c# to get the events, both of them had Reminders.Overrides was null and the Reminders.UseDefault was true. (I would have thought that the default reminder should have 1 Override with the pop-up and the other should have had the Override is null.)

How do I tell the one without the reminder and the one with the pop-up?

Comment: I could not reproduce this. When I remove the default reminder in the UI, I get back an empty set and useDefault=false. Is is possible that you are using credentials of another user when viewing the event? Reminders depend on who is accessing the event.

Comment: Which UI are you using?
I am using a different user, this google-calendar stuff is very undocumented, the only way I could program is was to create a developer.gserviceaccount and a privatekey.p12.  I use my normal gmail account to access the calendar in Chrome.

Comment: You can try out stuff in the explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/ (but it will be authenticated as you, not your service account). If you are using a service account and only have it's credentials (not the Oauth2 token for your personal account) then you won't see the reminders from your private account.